Advise on adding & setting up a PF Sense router to a pre-existing network
Just wanted to get some advice on whether it is possible to split a WAN port to two seperate networks. Basically, I want to setup the router and open VPN portion in the guide Louis Rossmann showed in his recent tutorial video on FUTO but already have a network in place that I do not want to touch as there are multiple "smart" devices on WIFI which will be a major PITA to reconfigure.
If I remember correctly (I set this up several years ago, over 6+ months as it constantly kept breaking and driving me insane!) the network setup looks like this:
Telstra Modem/router/AP all in one setup as normal doing its own DHCP and DNS just with WIFI disabled. Yes, I know that is the wrong way to do things, I did want to use bridged mode but we have a landline so that is not possible. Disabling the router & AP portion and only using it as a modem stopped the landline from working. I spent a good 6 months trying to disable as much on the Telstra as I could but every time I changed 1 setting from default the landline stopped working so I eventually gave up and just disabled WIFI.
ASUS AX router setup as normal doing its own DHCP and DNS on a separate IP range.
Some devices are connected to the Telstra via ethernet, but most are connected to the ASUS as it has far more ethernet ports. All WIFI devices connect to the ASUS.
My main concern is the family has setup some Eufy Cameras (ugh yes I know, do you think they listened to me?) which are connecting to WIFI on the ASUS. We also have some smart power outlets and also smart fans connecting again to the ASUS WIFI. I would happily use the ASUS as the WIFI AP in the guide Louis setup, but I'm worried that will mean I have to go in and reconfigure all the "smart" devices which I did not setup in the first place, and I recall much cursing from others when trying to setup in the first place, so I really do not want to touch them.
So ideally, I'd love to a old PC we have as the PFSense router and get a cheap AP and set the guide up as a entirely separate network not touching anything pre-existing. How would I do that though when the WAN port from the modem is already taken up by the ASUS router?
Additionally, if I can I'd love to link the network at work so I can access stuff on my work PC or our synology NAS from home.
Thanks for the assistance.

Yes, it is possible to have two LANs connected to the internet over the same WAN. The simplest way is to have two routers immediately downstream from the modem, each serving their own LAN. You could write rules on these to allow desired traffic between the LANs. Please focus on a single question here. Each post here should have a single question that can be answered specifically. It sounds like you've already got a good guide to go along with, but you don't really give any details regarding what of Rossman's steps you've followed, how far you got, and where it went wrong.

A simple thing to keep in mind: This site really isn't about "advice" so much as it is about specific, clear, and practical questions.
